# Imported JS file has unknown properties

Tags: javascript

I want to load scripts and css files by one js file.

```
this.importCascadingStyleSheet = function(path){ // import CSS file
    var element = document.createElement("link");
    element.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
    element.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
    element.setAttribute("href", path);
    this.appendComponent(element);
}

this.importScript = function(path){ // import JS file
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = path;
    this.appendComponent(script);
}

this.appendComponent = function(cmp){ // append file to document
    document.head.appendChild(cmp);
}

this.getLibPath = function(){
    var dir = document.querySelector('script[src$="diagramViewer.js"]').getAttribute('src');
    var fileName = dir.split('/').pop();
    var parentDir = dir.replace('/' + fileName, ""); 
    var directoryName = parentDir.split('/').pop();
    return parentDir.replace('/' + directoryName, ""); 
}

this.importStyle = function(fileName){ // helper function
    this.importCascadingStyleSheet(this.libPath + "/style/" + fileName + ".css");
}

this.importSource = function(fileName){ // helper function
    this.importScript(this.libPath + "/client/" + fileName + ".js");
}

// Code starts here

this.libPath = this.getLibPath(); // get the directory of the library

this.importStyle("myFirstCssFile");

this.importSource("firstScript");
this.importSource("secondScript");
this.importSource("thirdScript");
```

I want to import all the files from this script. The path is correct. Somehow I can't use the functions from the other scripts. They are unknown.

In the network tab in the developer console all my files got imported. The css file works fine. All of my js files are empty.

The status is on `pending`.

What am I missing if the given path is correct?

Comment: Why reinvent this wheel? Browsers already do a great job of this, and if you really feel the need for programmatic control, there are plenty of existing resource loaders...

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to use them too soon. What you're doing will **start** the process of loading those scripts, which will then continue asynchronously. The functions defined by the scripts won't be accessible until the process completes, which will be later (tens or even hundreds of milliseconds later, depending on network performance).

You'll want to update `importSource`/`importScript` so it provides some means of your knowing that the script has finished being loaded. For instance, they could return promises.

On a vaguely-modern browser, for instance, `importScript` could look like this:

```
this.importScript = function(path){ // import JS file
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.onload = resolve;
        script.onerror = reject;
        script.src = path;
        this.appendComponent(script);
    });
};
```

`importSource` would want to return the return value from `importScript`:

```
this.importSource = function(fileName){ // helper function
    return this.importScript(this.libPath + "/client/" + fileName + ".js");
};
```

Then you might use `Promise.all` to wait for them all to load:

```
Promise.all([
    this.importSource("firstScript"),
    this.importSource("secondScript"),
    this.importSource("thirdScript")
])
.then(function() {
    // All good, use the functions
})
.catch(function() {
    // At least one of them failed to load
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help but I have to support IE 9 and Promises are not supported by the Internet Explorer :(

Comment: @MatthiasHermsen - You can use any of several Promise libraries in IE9. Just because *native* promises aren't supported doesn't mean you can't use them. (Or use plain callbacks, but the basic point above remains: You need to provide a way to wait for completion. Promises do that in a way that's easy to aggregate.)

Comment: the file status in the network tab is on `pending` so I think you might be true